# Чому імена трансформуються до невпізнаваності (Зуза, Зоня, Зося)?

Tags: власні-назви

Три сусідки-бабусі серед односельчан відомі як Зуза, Зоня і Зося. Яке ж було здивування, коли стало відомо, що за документами Зуза - Сусанна, а Зоня і Зося- Софії. Чому так трансформувались їхні імена? Які мовні процеси могли з ними відбутися?

Comment: В якому це реґіоні?

Comment: Села Волинської області.

Comment: Це просто польські варіанти імен. Їхнє початкове З з німецької, де на початку слова С перед голосною переходить у З.